# Why does Git tell me "error: No such remote 'origin' " when i try git remote remove origin?

Tags: git, heroku

I created a project and I want to send it to heroku but I have a problem with the URL so I wanted remove remote.origin.url=http://exp and replace that with remote.heroku.url=http://exp. I can add new remote in git config but i can't delete remote.origin or change URL.

Everytime terminal said "error: No such remote: 'origin' " but i see it exists when i type git config --list.

already try :

- git remote remove origin
- git remote set-url origin http://exp
- restart the computer

When i type git config --list --show-origin, result:

```
file:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig    credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig   user.email=exp
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig   user.password=exp
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig   user.name=Israil exp
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig   http.postbuffer=157286400
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig   remote.origin.url=https://git.heroku.com/graphql-flutter-cours.git
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        core.precomposeunicode=true
file:.git/config        remote.heroku.url=https://git.heroku.com/api-graphql-project.git
file:.git/config        remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Can you tell me how to remove remote.origin from git config?

Comment: Please include the output of `git remote` into your question.

Comment: `git config --list --show-origin`

Comment: You have `remote.origin.url` in the global `.gitconfig`. Remove it from there — it must be in local. Then `cd repo` and use `git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/graphql-flutter-cours.git` to add it locally.

Comment: If the problem is solved please do not leave the question open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this answer of phd resolved my problem.

You have remote.origin.url in the global .gitconfig. Remove it from there — it must be in local. Then cd repo and use git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/graphql-flutter-cours.git to add it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--unset` to remove remote.origin.url from the global config of git :
`git config --global --unset remote.origin.url`